# Iterating through the result list in jpa and setting the firstResult,maxResults

Tags: jpa-2.0

i have a query which is giving the large result suppose it is 1,00,000.I need to show all these records in a grid in UI.So i am using

```
TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery =  entityManager.createQuery(cq); 
   typedQuery.setFirstResult(0);
   typedQuery.setMaxResults(1000);
List<Object> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

When this query is executed i am able to see only 1000 records in UI.It is not fetching the next set of results.But i need to see all the records whatever that query is returning.How can i do this.Can any one tell me.It is very urgent to me.I am using JPA criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything and not just the first 1000 results, why do you call `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()`? Remove them, and the query will retrieved everything:

```
TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cq); 
List<Object> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: i am saving the total result into a column in another table.So while saving i am getting packet size is too large.Thats why i am searching fpr pagination.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to fetch next set of result?

If you use the query shown in your post as is, you will always get first 1000 records because that is what you are asking.

You would need to call this query repeatedly by setting `setFirstResult`to 0 then 1000 then 2000 and so on until the result list is empty.